# Is this checkmate?

Tags: analysis, checkmate

```
[fen "3Q4/8/k7/5p2/q2p1Pp1/2p3P1/K1P5/3R4 w - - 0 1"]
```

I recently started playing chess and was doing some puzzles online. It says that this move is checkmate but I don't see why white can't move to b1. Can someone please explain?

Comment: It means that mate will happen not that it has already occured.  See Phishmasters full  answer below.

Comment: Maybe this puzzle shows the tower in the wrong color (that is, it should have been a black tower instead of a white one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the white king can still move to b1.

That said, Kb1 Qb4+; any Qb2 is mate.

```
 [FEN "3Q4/8/k7/5p2/q2p1Pp1/2p3P1/K1P5/3R4 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Kb1 Qb4+ 2. Ka2 Qb2#
```